# ng-bootstrap two collapse not working as needed in angular 6

Tags: angular, sidebar, ng-bootstrap

Am trying to make a sidebar by using ng-bootrap and i am using collapse

[ng-bootrap collaspe](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/collapse/examples)

> by collapse i trying to trigger two collapse alternatively

example :-

1) if home button is clicked only its submenu options should show other setting submenu should be closed.

[homecollpase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSvsn.png)

2) if setting button is clicked only its submenu options should show other home submenu should be closed.

[setting collapse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43mZK.png)

> but in my case collapse is not working accordingly

collapse opens but other collapse doesn't close automatically

> any ideas how will it work? used code shown below

```
<p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"
          [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    home parent
  </button>
</p>
<div id="collapseExample" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      Ysubmenu 1
      <br>
      Ysubmenu 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="isCollapsedsetting = !isCollapsedsetting"
          [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsedsetting" aria-controls="collapseExamplesetting">
setting parent
</button>
</p>
<div id="collapseExamplesetting" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsedsetting">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      Ysubmenu 1
      <br>
      Ysubmenu 2    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just use a unique variable, e.g. "panelCollapsed" and use (click)="panelCollapsed='one' and [ngbCollapse]="panelCollapsed!='one' (or you can use ng-acordeaon https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples

Comment: i have did the same in the code kindly check the code.

Comment: Your'e using two variables: "isCollapsed"  and "isCollapsedsetting". I suggest you use a unique variable "panelCollapsed" I create a simple example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xzcggn?file=app/collapse-basic.html

Comment: thanks your ansewer worked ... i am using in sidebar menu

Comment: what if we have multiple collapse den the code will fail ?

Comment: just change panelCollapsed != 'uno' by panelCollapsed != ' **something** ' and (click)="panelCollapsed=panelCollapsed == 'uno'?null:'uno'" by (click)="panelCollapsed=panelCollapsed == ' **something** '?null:' **something** "